# How to properly use appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, appendchild

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:last").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $("a:last").attr("href");
        var page = url.slice(-2).trim();
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        $(newDiv).addClass("content");
        $(newDiv).addClass(page);
        $(newDiv).load(url);
        document.getElementById("main").appendChild($(newDiv)); 
    });
});
```

I want to create a new `div` and load some content into it, then append it to the "main" `div`, but I get a TypeError:

> Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.

I already have a div with `id="main"`, why can't I append my new div to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `appendChild()` expects a `node` object as its parameter, but here you are passing a jquery object. You can fix it by passing a node object,

```
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(newDiv);
```

And since you are using jquery, you can use its own `append()` function,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:last").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $("a:last").attr("href");
        var page = url.slice(-2).trim();
        var newDiv = $("<div>");
        newDiv.addClass("content");
        newDiv.addClass(page);
        newDiv.load(url);
        $("#main").append(newDiv); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're mixing up jQuery and plain old JS. The error itself is because you're proving a jQuery object to `appendChild()` when it's expecting a DOMElement. As you're using jQuery anyway you may as well use that to create your elements. Try this:

```
$("a:last").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $("a:last").attr("href");
    var page = url.slice(-2).trim();
    $('<div />').addClass('content ' + page).appendTo('#main').load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(newDiv) is a jquery object, not the node. You need to pass the node in. This will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:last").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $("a:last").attr("href");
        var page = url.slice(-2).trim();
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        $(newDiv).addClass("content");
        $(newDiv).addClass(page);
        $(newDiv).load(url);
        document.getElementById("main").appendChild(newDiv); 
    });
});
```